# Evaluation and assignment order of SET

Tags: mysql, sql

The [MySQL manual on user variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) says that

> As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement. For example, to increment a variable, this is okay:
>
> ```
> SET @a = @a + 1;
> ```
>
> For other statements, such as SELECT, you might get the results you expect, but this is not guaranteed. In the following statement, you might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an assignment second:
>
> ```
> SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ...;
> ```
>
> However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined.

This is apparently comparing apples and oranges. SELECT @a:=@a+1; would be the equivalent, and would be just as fine as SET @a=@a+1, since @a+1 has always to be evaluated before assigning its value to @a.

However, if we do the same for SET as for SELECT, ie.

```
SET @b=@a,@a=@a+1;
```

is the value of @b guaranteed to contain the value of @a from before executing the statement? Or can it contain the incremented value?

The following questions can be asked:

1. Will the expressions be evaluated from left to right? Ie. after

   ```
   SET @a =(@v:='x'), @b = (@v:='y');
   ```

   is @v guaranteed to be 'y'?
2. Will the assignments be done from left to right? Ie., after

   ```
   SET @v='x',@v='y';
   ```

   is @v guaranteed to be 'y'?
3. Will all evaluations happen strictly before all assignments? Ie., after

   ```
   SET @a='x',@v=@a,@a='y';
   ```

   is @v guaranteed to contain the value of @a from before the statement is executed? ("If any variable assignment in a SET statement fails, the entire statement fails and no variables are changed" from the manual suggests this, though it would also allow SET to save the old values and restore them when an assignment fails.)

Although the [MySQL manual on stored program variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-variables.html) says that 'Variables can be set directly with the SET statement. See [Section 13.7.4.1, “SET Syntax for Variable Assignment”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-variable.html).', I noticed that when I do

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST_SET()
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    SET @v='BEFORE',@a='BEFORE';
    SET @a='x',@v=@a,@a='y',@a=(SELECT * FROM doesntexist);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

and then

```
CALL TEST_SET();
SELECT @a,@v;
```

apparently the SET did evaluations and assignments strictly in alternation from left to right, until it hit the error. This is different behavior from executing the SET outside of the stored procedure, and no "If any variable assignment in a SET statement fails, ... no variables are changed." I am confused.

The [MySQL manual on SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-variable.html) does not provide answers to these questions.

Please note that it does not help try the statements with MySQL and see what result is obtained. I want to know what is guaranteed.

Comment: I would say that the "as a general rule" comes pretty close to saying that you *can* depend on the order of evaluation in a `set`.